# Angular 1.5 and setting a selected option for a dynamic generated select?

Tags: angularjs

I have nested data objects that I want to show to a user based on the filters they have selected. I am a bit new to angular but finding how to solve this problem has taken me a while now and not really got anything good.

```
  <tr ng-repeat="stockItem in stock | filter : stockFilter ">
   <td>{{stockItem.dateCreated | date:'dd/MM/yyyy (HH:mm)'}}</td>
   <td>{{stockItem.sku}}</td>
   <td>
    <select class="form-control">
    <option ng-repeat="supplierOrderStock in stockItem.supplierStock | filter : supplierSelectionFilter"
            value="{{supplierOrderStock.supplierId}}" >
              £{{supplierOrderStock.price}}
      </option>
    </select>
  </td>
 </tr>
```

I have check boxes on the top of the page and when you check or uncheck them the drop downs get updated with the filtered data.

Problem is that the SELECTED drop down is random, usually the first one that was selected on initial render.

I just want the cheapest value to be shown in the drop downs and the way the data is sorted that is always going to be the first select option.

How do I set the drop down selected value, for each nested repeat to be either the cheapest one or just simply the always the first drop down??

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use the [NgOption](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) directive instead:

```
<div class="col col-50">
    <span>Orientation</span>    <br>            
    <select name="orientation" id="orientation" ng-options="option.label for option in data.filters.basics.orientations track by option.id" ng-model="data.selectedOrientation">
    </select>
</div>
```

In my case the data.selectedOrientation is the default ng-model that i had to setup in the controller:

```
$scope.data.selectedOrientation = $scope.data.filters.basics.orientations[($scope.data.selections.basics.orientations[0]-1)]
```

Comment: Thanks for answering but I tried that a few times and could not get it to work the way I wanted...

Answer (score 1):

If you dont want to change your dom element jsut add a ng-model to it

```
 <tr ng-repeat="stockItem in stock | filter : stockFilter ">
   <td>{{stockItem.dateCreated | date:'dd/MM/yyyy (HH:mm)'}}</td>
   <td>{{stockItem.sku}}</td>
   <td>
    <select class="form-control">
    <option ng-repeat="supplierOrderStock in stockItem.supplierStock | filter : supplierSelectionFilter" ng-modal="yourModelForThisDom"
            value="{{supplierOrderStock.supplierId}}" >
              £{{supplierOrderStock.price}}
      </option>
    </select>
  </td>
 </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

After learning a bit more I finally realised that it will be much easier if all the data is stored and filtered on the Model and collections within.

```
<select class="form-control" ng-show="stockItem.supplierStockFiltered.length > 0"
        ng-model="stockItem.selectedSupplier"
        ng-options="option as getSupplierDropDownText(option) for option in stockItem.supplierStockFiltered track by option.price"></select>
<span ng-show="stockItem.supplierStockFiltered.length == 0 || stockPackItem.supplierStockFiltered == null ">
    No Stock
</span>
```

So when the data loads or when ever I click on any check boxes, I just use `angular.forEach(` in the controller to set the Selected Item based on what ever I filtered out. The actual two fields I am binding too are not contained int he the data that comes back from the server. But in JS you can just dynamically add those fields before the HTML binds and it works great!

The HTML is much cleaner and I have much better control over the models.

End of the day I had to go do this any way because now I need to save all the selected drop down values... and now because the Selected item is bound to the model.. its easy peasy. I just serialise the models and use the data on the server.